# Resource leak when caching a response

Tags: netty

I am using netty 4.0.26.Final to develop a proxy server (based in the [HexDumpProxy](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/proxy/package-summary.html) example) which can cache the responses to some type of request. So when receiving a request which its response is cached, it will return the response cached without following the pipeline to the host.

Now I have the logic to do it running without errors but when I activate the ResourceLeakDetector to paranoid level, I get a resource leak error (I think) due to the ByteBuf inside the response stored in the cache.

Here is the code of my handler place in the pipeline before the [HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler.html). The ResultMessage inserted in the cache implements a ByteBufHolder.

```
public class CacheHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler {

  private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, ResultMessage> cache;

  private String cacheKey;

  public CacheHandler(ConcurrentHashMap<String, ResultMessage> cache) {
    this.cache = cache;
  }

  @Override
  public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    // Check if the message is an instance of Message, if not we can not cache its value
    if (msg instanceof Message) {
        Message myMsg = (Message) msg;
        // Check if there is a cache key for this Message,
        // again if no cache key is available the message is not suitable for caching
        cacheKey = myMsg.getCacheKey();
        if (cacheKey != null) {
            ResultMessage resultMsg = cache.get(cacheKey);
            if (resultMsg != null) {
                // Response is actually cached and returned directly
                ctx.writeAndFlush(resultMsg.retain()).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
            } else {
                // Response is not cached yet, it is necessary to follow the pipeline to the host
                ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
            }
        } else {
            ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
        }
    } else {
        ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
    // Check if it is a response to a request suitable for caching
    if (cacheKey != null && msg instanceof ResultMessage) {
        ResultMessage resultMsg = (ResultMessage) msg;
        cache.put(cacheKey, resultMsg.retain());
    }
    ctx.write(msg, promise);
  }
}
```

And this is the error logged

```
 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-4] ERROR io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
```

Any help to avoid this resource leak will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realized that I am not releasing the original message received in the channel before returning the cached message. So the solution is to release it before returning.

```
  ...
  // Response is actually cached and returned directly
  myMsg.release();
  ctx.writeAndFlush(resultMsg.retain()).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
  ...
```